# Bootstrap collapsible chat widget issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/collapsible-chat-widget
In the collapsible chat widget above if the chat is open any controls on the same level as the widget cannot be clicked. Is there a way to allow other controls to be clicked when the chat is open?

Comment: I see it's pushing `.container` down when it expands, this could be an issue if you have content outside of this container as it will overlap in front of content.

Comment: Ok cheers, so how can this be resolved?

Comment: I'm not certain that my understanding of your question is correct. I am able to interact with the text entry box, scroll, interact with the button, and toggle the display state of the widget. What do you mean when you say that controls on the same level as the widget cannot be clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue could be due to the container height growing as the chat widget expands which would cover up any content outside of `.container` with the full width `.container` element.

You can avoid this by removing the surrounding `.container`, `.row` and `.col-md-5` and wrap the widget in its own wrapper setting a width and `display: inline-block;` to stop the container from overlapping other content.

See http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/x8G9R for an example. There are a number of ways to achieve the same result, this is just one example.

I've used `position: fixed;` with my example as it would presumably be useful to be visible whilst scrolling.

Comment: When viewed in a mobile device the widget cannot be collapsed. Is there anyway to sort this?

Comment: @Danny is it due to the close link being out of the viewport? If so, adding a media query and setting the widget to `position:fixed;` and set `left` and `right`.